# interface 2420Packet not found Tinyos

Tags: tinyos

every time i tried to get the Rssi value from a received packet i get this erreur

```
interface 2420Packet not found
```

my code is

```
message_localization_t msg=(message_localization_t *) Packet->data;
int_8 Rssi_Value=call CC240Packet.getRssi(msg);
```

And i tried to do this:

```
unit_16 Rssi_Value=Packet->strangh;
```

but when i tried to complicate the module file i get this erreur please help me!!

Answer (score 0):

Try with `CC2420Packet` instead of `2420Packet` when using interface.

Answer (score 0):

it didn't work with me either but i finally found the solution 
in order to get the value of Rssi from the received packet i wrote the following code:

in the receive part of:

```
 event message_t* Receive.receive(message_t* pck,uint_8 len){ 
 unit_8 Rssi_value =pck->metadata[1]//for Rssi value check message_t specification
```